# Move from one view to another view in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swiftui

I'm new to swiftUI and doing a login application form.There are Email-Id and password textfields and a Login button. On clicking of Login button it should move to next view. Please note that I dont want to navigate using Navigation Link & Navigation View. I tried the following code. But the next view loads in current view itself like in the second pic

```
struct Login: View {

  @State private var success = false

                TextField("Email ID", text: $emailId , onEditingChanged: { (isChanged) in
                    if !isChanged {
                        if self.textFieldValidatorEmail(self.emailId) {
                            self.isEmailValid = true
                        } else {
                            self.isEmailValid = false
                            self.emailId = ""
                        }
                    }
                })
                 TextField("Password", text: $password)
                    .modifier(customViewModifier(roundedCornes: 6,  textColor: .black))
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .padding(\[.leading, .trailing\], 100)


               Button(action: {
                        btnLoginClicked()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Sign In")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 30)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(.custom("Open Sans", size: 28))
                        
                })
             if(success)
                {

                    SelectLocation()
                }
              }
              



func btnLoginClicked()
                   {
                     success = true
                   }
            }
```

SelectLocation.swift is another swiftUI file where I need to show other details

Following are the screens
[image]

[image]

The second pic is combination of Login.swift file and SelectLocation.swift file .

Plz let me correct where am I going wrong

Comment: How do you want to navigate, if not using a NavigationLink? Are you just trying to avoid the navigation bar?

Comment: @George I want to use Navigation bar , but my app is specifically for iPad and if I use NavigationView I get the split view navigation bar which is the default one. My app design has a regular navigation bar which we use to have in Obj-C app. I want the same appearance in swiftUI app. So I din't go for NavigationLink

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your login items in `if(success)` `else` brunch. Now they're displayed in any case

And perfectly you'd move that logic out, so I suggest you using something like:

```
struct RootView: View {
    @State
    var success = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if success {
            SelectLocation()
        } else {
            LoginView(onSuccess: {
                success = true
            })
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    let onSuccess: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        // your login views
    }
    
    func btnLoginClicked() {
        onSuccess()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is based on a condition if success is true then navigate to SelectLocation , else show Login view. But, in general I would like to navigate to another swiftUI file in case of button click

Comment: @Honey that's why I'm modifying `@State` with a closure, you can have all `RootView`, `LoginView` and `SelectLocation` in different files