# How to link my Login screen to my Home screen SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uibutton

I am stuck on linking my login screen to my Main screen. Both have been created separately and I have used the Button function to create the login button and it goes to another screen with the email I have logged in with but that's not what I want as I want my home screen to open up instead.

```
             Button(action: model.login) {
                     Text("LOGIN")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("Color1"))
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
            }
            .padding(.top, 22)
```

My MainView code starting

```
     struct MainView: View {
     @State private var isShowing = false
  
     var body: some View {
  
     NavigationView {
          
     ZStack {
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Your question is pretty vague. Could you please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can copy-paste it into your Xcode to assist you better?

Comment: you may want to have a look at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757560/move-from-one-view-to-another-view-in-swiftui/68757673#68757673

Answer (score 1):

In your `App` struct add a `State` var `isLoggedin` passing it to the `loginView` and toggling it from there.

This is how I implemented.

```
struct TestApp: App {
    
    @State var isLoggedin: Bool = false
    
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            if isLoggedin {
                ContentView()
            } else {
                LoginView(isLoggedin: $isLoggedin)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct LoginView: View {
    
    @Binding var isLoggedin: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            isLoggedin = true
        }, label: {
            Text("Login")
        })
    }
}
```

This way you can pick which view to show. `ContentView` to `LoginView`.

Comment: There is no need also no use case to Binding here, you can use a closure for this work! Or you can inject a Model to content view without using a closure on view! Ps: your answer is not usable in real use case!

Comment: I would make a model that I would inject to both the `LoginView` and the `ContentView` which would include the `isLoggedIn`.  I would have the same approach as the above code. Whats wrong with that... could you elaborate?

Comment: The process of loading takes time and we don’t know when it would be finished! Then we need at first place a completion handler for that since we got the completion handler that means we don’t need binding! Because we will receive for sure newValue for work on ContentView!

Comment: The model should do all that work, no need for a completion handler. Once all the information for the user is saved (username, email, icon, api token ...) `isLoggedIn` should toggle. And should toggle back when these are removed... I still don't understand what the problem is. :)

Comment: You missed the point that I mentioned 2 deferent ways! Read my last comments! One way is injecting the modal or making StateObject and the second way working on view without having any models! In each way we would need completion handler for sure and there is no need to Binding in each way! Also 100% your answer is Not practical to use.

Comment: I disagree if a completion handler works this would work but in my opinion like you stated I would inject a `StateObject` model. But my answer here is to so get the idea across... most of the logic stays the same with `StateObject`. :)